# How to select all checkBoxes in table column -Vaadin 7

Tags: vaadin, checkboxlist, selectall

I got one column with checkboxes, it is generated by column generator, how can i set them all checked ?

Thanks.

Comment: Also I try use JS but this dosent work  - the raelly value dosent change seem look like fake :S

Comment: Just to precise the question - do you want them all to be checked when table is initialized or later i.e. as a result of user's interaction, etc. ?

Comment: @PDave I've got the same requirement. Need to add a check box at header level of Table in Vaadin. Which will allow the user to select all and deselect all. How did you added the check box at header level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate the column mark the checkboxes.

```
cb.setData("x");
```

Then:

```
Iterator<Component> iterator = table.iterator();
while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
  Component c = iterator.next();
  if (c instanceof AbstractField) {
    AbstractField<Object> af = (AbstractField<Object>) c;
    if ("x".equals(af.getData())) {
      af.setValue(true);
    }
  }
}
```

(The code is not tested.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a dummy example:

```
public class CheckBoxColumnGenerator implements Table.ColumnGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Property<?> prop = source.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty(columnId);
        return new CheckBox(null, prop);
    }
}

...

Table table = new Table();
table.addContainerProperty("checkbox", Boolean.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("label", String.class, null);
table.addItem(new Object[] { true, "row#1" }, 1);
table.addItem(new Object[] { false, "row#2" }, 2);
table.addItem(new Object[] { true, "row#3" }, 3);
table.addItem(new Object[] { false, "row#4" }, 4);
table.addGeneratedColumn("checkbox", new CheckBoxColumnGenerator());
```

Then:

```
for (Object itemId : table.getItemIds()) {
    table.getItem(itemId).getItemProperty("checkbox").setValue(true);
}
```